# Algorithm for iteratively testing 2d grid connectiveness

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, flood-fill

Let's say that I have a 2D grid size that can hold either a zero or one at each index. The grid starts off as full of zeros and then ones are progressively added. At each step, I want to verify that adding the next one will not prevent the zeros from forming one connected component (using a 4-connected grid with north, east, south, and west neighbors).

What is a fast algorithm that will iteratively test a 2D grid for connectedness?

Currently I am using a flood fill at each iteration, but I feel there should be a faster algorithm that uses information from previous iterations.

*Additionally*, the method that places the ones will sometimes unplace the ones even if they don't disconnect the grid, so the algorithm I'm looking for needs to be able to handle that.

Comment: I found the proper name for this is dynamic connectivity. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity) gives several algorithms for general graphs, but the answer below works better for my grid case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is inspired by Kruskal's algorithm for maze generation.

I am defining the neighborhood of a square as its 8 surrounding squares, including the outside of the grid (the neighborhood of a corner square is its 3 surrounding squares plus the outside, so 4 "squares" total).

Put the 1s in sets so that any two neighboring 1s belong to the same set. Treat the outside of the grid as one big 1 (which means the first set contains it). When adding a 1, you only need to check its neighbors.

Below are all the possible cases. To make it easier to visualize, I'll number the sets starting from 1 and use the set number instead of the 1 in each square that contains a 1. The outside belongs to the set numbered 1. You can also use this to simplify the implementation. The brackets indicate the newly placed 1.

If the new 1 has no neighboring 1, then it belongs to a new set.

```
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 0 0
 0 0 0[3]0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
```

If it has one neighboring 1, then it belongs to the same set.

```
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 0 0
 0 0[2]0 0
 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
```

If it has multiple neighboring 1s, and all neighbors belonging to the same set are direct neighbors, then you can merge the sets and the new 1 belongs to the resulting set. You don't need to check for a disconnection.

```
 0 0 0 0 0                0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 0 0                0 1 0 0 0
 0 0[3]1 0       ->       0 0[1]1 0
 0 0 1 1 0                0 0 1 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0                0 0 1 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0                0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 0 0                0 1 0 0 0
 0 2 0 1 0       ->       0 1 0 1 0
[3]0 0 1 0               [1]0 0 1 0
 1 1 1 0 0                1 1 1 0 0
```

If it has multiple neighboring 1s of the same set, but they are not all direct neighbors, then you have a disconnection.

```
 0 0 0 0 0                0 0 0 0 0 <- first group of 0s
 0 2 0 0 0                0 1 0 0 0
 0 0[3]1 0       ->       0 0[1]1 0
 0 1 0 1 1                0 1 0 1 1
 1 0 0 0 0                1 0 0 0 0 <- second group of 0s

 0 0 0 0 0 <- first group of 0s
 0 0 1 0 0
 0 1 0 1 1 
[1]1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 <- second group of 0s

 0 0 0 0 0                0 0 0 0 0
 0 2 0 0 0                0 1 0 0 0
 0 2 0 1 0       ->       0 1 0 1 0
[3]0 0 1 0               [1]0 0 1 0
 0{1}1 0 0      lone 0 -> 0{1}1 0 0
```

In this last example, the 1 marked `{1}` and the outside technically are neighbors, but not from the point of view of the newly placed 1.

In the general case, when removing a 1 that has multiple neighboring 1s, you need to check whether they are still connected after the removal (for example, by running a pathfinder between them). If not, separate them in different sets.

If you know the 0s are all connected, then you can check locally: removing a 1 will not split the set it belongs to if its neighbors are all direct neighbors (careful with the outside, though). It will if there is are multiple "gaps" in its neighborhood.

In the special case where you only remove the 1s in the reverse order you added them, you can keep track of which newly added 1s join multiple sets (and even what the sets are at that moment, if you need). These will split their set when you remove them later on.

Comment: An optimization is that the thorough check is only necessary when the 1s are not adjacent. For example adding a 1 in the middle of the second to last case is fine.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. A thorough check is necessary whenever you place a 1 in the neighborhood (the 8 surrounding squares) of at least two other 1s that belong to the same set (including the outside).

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify the possible cases. There is actually no need for a flood fill anywhere.

Comment: The optimization I was talking about is the same thing you added in your edit. Although I didn't realize it gets rid of the need for the thorough check.

Comment: When removing a 1, you can determine locally whether or not removing it will create one or more new disjoint sets.  If it does there will be gaps in its neighbours.  In that case you can use BFS on each neighbour region to determine the extent of each neighbouring set, and reassign all but the largest one.

Comment: Another option for removing 1s is by using a link/cut tree. To do this though the 1s need to be removed in the reverse order that they are added (which is true for my case).

Comment: @MattTimmermans True if the 0s are all connected. I wasn't sure that was OP's case everytime, but it now seems like it must be.

Comment: @BennettBernardoni You don't need a complex structure such as a link/cut tree. Just keep track of the 1s you add. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Nelfeal The problem is I was using disjoint sets and if you implement it with path compression there is no fast way of disconnecting sets. For a while I tried putting the new 1 at the root of the tree and then disconnecting by removing its children. But this made find_set linear time complexity as there is not path compression or union by rank (which wouldn't preserve the tree). So instead, I speed this up to O(log(n)) by using link/cut trees.